# Order By with please select as first choice

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-order-by

I want to order a column by name in Ascending order with --Please Select-- as the first choice. 
Is there a way i can change my code to allow for this?
Sort by ID with --Please Select-- on top

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    firmNetworkID,
    name
FROM dbo.tbl_firmNetwork
UNION
  SELECT '0', '--Please Select--'
ORDER BY firmNetworkID
```

Sort by Name

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    firmNetworkID,
    name
FROM dbo.tbl_firmNetwork
UNION
  SELECT '0', '--Please Select--'
ORDER BY [name] ASC
```

Thanks

Comment: '--Please Select--' as in a drop down? You can alternatively replace with a '?' and in the next line the user can type in the desired column name.

Comment: Hey @SwastikRajGhosh can you explain what you mean there ? it sounds really useful for a dynamic query

Comment: It can be implemented using a script. IS it ok to implement a script or you need only SQL?

Comment: Add a CASE in the ORDER BY (se answer below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    firmNetworkID,
    name,
    1 P
FROM dbo.tbl_firmNetwork
UNION
    SELECT '0', '--Please Select--', 0 
ORDER BY P, [name] ASC
```

Comment: Actually, no need for the extra P-column, use a CASE in ORDER BY instead (answer below).

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra column for sorting only. In the Select after the union you can put there something that will allways come first

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
firmNetworkID,
name as SortOrder,
name
FROM dbo.tbl_firmNetwork

UNION

SELECT '0','___', '--Please Select--'
ORDER BY SortOrder ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's no need for extra column. Just USE a CASE in the ORDER BY:

```
 SELECT firmNetworkID,
     name
 FROM
 (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        firmNetworkID,
        name
    FROM dbo.tbl_firmNetwork
    UNION ALL
      SELECT '0', '--Please Select--'
    ORDER BY [name] ASC 
 ) AS i
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN i.name='--Please Select--' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, i.name
```